# formula to find the range of a function

Tags: functions

I have this function

> f(x) = |x|/x

and I would like to find the range of that function which is y=+1 or y=-1

My question: is there any formula to find the range of functions (much more complicated ones) without graph?

Edit: Also, How is this proven: Via induction or how?

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{for $x$ > 0} \\
-1, & \text{for $x$ < 0}
\end{cases}$

Thank you

Comment: In general (and most of the time), no.

Comment: The range of a function is a set, and every set can be the range of a function.  It is isn't clear what you mean by "any formula to find the range of functions".

Comment: ok, but what about the function in the question, I found the range at wolframalpha, what do i write to explain how that range was found? or just y=+1 or y=-1

Comment: In this case the range of $f$ is the set $\{1,-1\}$.  Here "range" means the set of values that the function can produce, when applied to the domain.  It was not stated in your initial question what the domain of $f$ is assumed to be.  Among real numbers, $f(x) = |x|/x$ is not defined at $x=0$.  The Edit notes that $f(x)$ can be evaluated as $1$ for $x \gt 0$ and as $-1$ for $x \lt 0$.  This is not hard to prove if you define the absolute value of $x$ in a similar fashion (that is, $|x| = x$ if $x \ge 0$ and $|x| = -x$ if $x \lt 0$).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such formula for the general case.

But if the function admits an inverse, then the domain if the latter would be the image of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

In case of f(x) = |x|/x,, you can tell it from the graph,,
Usually we find the inverse of a function (of whom we are trying to find the range) and the the domain of the Inverse function is the range of the original function...
But in this case the function is onto, and inverse of onto functions doesn't exist. ..